# Is it ok to plant 2 or even 3 of a vegetable plant in a 25 gallon smart pot

Tags: vegetables

I was wondering if I could plant 3 bell pepper plants in one 25 gallon smart pot and one zucchini/ one yellow squash in another 25 gallon smart pot? Tomatoes and cucumbers have their own pots. I don’t like this idea but the wife is reluctant to buy more soil and pots.